# Edit function in Wordpress to add id AutoNumber for heading

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function in wordpress to add `id=` AutoNumber for heading in content:

```
    function anchor_content_headings($content) {
  $content = preg_replace_callback("/\<h([1|2|3])\>(.*?)\<\/h([1|2|3])\>/", function ($matches) {
    $hTag = $matches[1];
    $title = $matches[2];




   $slug = "" . sanitize_title_with_dashes($title ); 

    return '<a href="#'. $slug .'"><h'. $hTag .' id="' . $slug . '">' . $title . '</h'. $hTag .'></a>';
  }, $content);
  return $content; 
}
add_filter('the_content', 'anchor_content_headings');
```

The function outputs:

> <2 id=#title-test>title test</h2>
>
> <2 id=#title-two>title two</h2>
>
> <3 id=#title-test-test>title test test</h3>

I want edit function to output:

> <2 id=#1>title test </h2>
>
> <2 id=#2>title test test </h2>
>
> <3 id=#3>title test test </h3>

This mod is because there are problems with non-English languages ​​with their use of JavaScript

Comment: `$slug = "" . sanitize_title_with_dashes($title ); }`

are you sure this line must end with `}` ?

Comment: There was a mistake the amendment was made
Required  to output:

<2 id=#1>title test </h2>

<2 id=#2>title test test </h2>

<3 id=#3>title test test </h3>

Comment: Are there solutions?